# Issue with win32 FillRect() function in C

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to draw a 4x4 grid of 100x100 rectangles with 50px between them for a 2048 game. I have followed a tutorial and tried to make a drawCases() function to be called on window creation. The window is created and everything works (except the rectangles are not drawn) if I comment out the following line:

```
FillRect(hdc,&rectangles[i][j],(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
```

Otherwise the program crashes.
Here is the whole function:

```
void drawCases(HWND hwnd){
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); 

    // Error Check
    if(!hdc)
        return;

    RECT clientRect;
    RECT rectangles[4][4];
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&clientRect); // Get the window's client area RECT
    FillRect(hdc,&clientRect,(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    int leftStart = (clientRect.right)/2 - 200;
    int topStart = (clientRect.bottom)/2 - 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++){
            int k = j * 150;
            int n = i * 150;
            rectangles[i][j].left = k + leftStart;
            rectangles[i][j].right = k + leftStart + 100;
            rectangles[i][j].top = topStart + n;
            rectangles[i][j].bottom = topStart + n + 100;
            FillRect(hdc,&rectangles[i][j],(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145137(v=vs.85).aspx) is the place to draw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the possible mistake:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++){
```

Replace `i++` with `j++`